# 404 File not found after apache update to 2.4

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

The following url does not work after updating apache from version 2.2 to 2.4.

```
http://localhost/front_application_stb/proxy.php/no/user/check-auth?&api_version=1&...
```

If I open:

```
http://localhost/front_application_stb/proxy.php
```

without params or change the url to:

```
http://localhost/front_application_stb/proxy.php?no/user/check-auth&api_version=1&...
```

everything works fine. The point is that it's used by other app and it has to work the way it is. Mod rewrite it turned on.

.htaccess file in front_application_stb is as follows:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.(htm|html|php)$
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !application_stb/.* [NC]
    RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
</IfModule>
```

I would really appreciate some help with this issue. I'm working on it for too long.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uninstalling

`libapache2-mod-php5filter`

and installing

`libapache2-mod-php5`

solved the problem. I'm not sure was was the cause of the problem though.